# Does just adding a static class in an application cause a get to be issued?

Tags: c#

I inherited this code where the app class is called when the application starts. I don't understand one thing. Specifically in this code what causes the DataAccess class to be created? Note that in the application there is no reference anywhere else to the DataAccess class or App.dataAccess.  Even so the class gets created.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    static DataAccess dataAccess;

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new Test.MainPage();
    }

    public static DataAccess DataAccess
    {
        get
        {
            if (dataAccess == null)
            {
                dataAccess = new DataAccess();
            }
            return dataAccess;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The class is instantiated in the property's getter when a reference to App.DataAccess is made. It's an application of the Singleton pattern. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Accessing the static property `App.DataAccess` will cause DataAccess to be created....

Comment: There's no reference to DataAccess or dataAccess in any other part of the application than here so I am still unsure of how it gets called.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the constructor of DataAccess, and inspect the call stack to see if you can figure out where it is being instantiated. This is very tough to answer without more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is almost certainly a reference to the property if DataAccess is being instantiated. If this is a WCF application, have you checked for any clues in the XAML binding?

Comment: This should be comment

Answer (score 0):

If you compile your project in Realese configuration it will optimize the solution and deletes unreachable code.